# How to fix this this error in `pip-9.03` and `python-2.6`

Tags: pip, python-2.6

I installed `python-2.6` and then `setuptools` and finally `pip-9.0.3` on my machine.I added the path of pip in my `PATH` variable.now when i type `pip` in my cmd, it returns this error.

```
C:\Users\Asus>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 572, in load_
entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2769, in load
_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2422, in load

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2428, in reso
lve
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.3-py2.6.egg\pip\__init__.py", line
 45, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.3-py2.6.egg\pip\vcs\mercurial.py",
 line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.3-py2.6.egg\pip\download.py", line
 37, in <module>
    from pip.utils.ui import DownloadProgressBar, DownloadProgressSpinner
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.3-py2.6.egg\pip\utils\ui.py", line
 57, in <module>
    _BaseBar = _select_progress_class(IncrementalBar, Bar)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.3-py2.6.egg\pip\utils\ui.py", line
 50, in _select_progress_class
    six.text_type().join(characters).encode(encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp720
```

unfortunately this website `www.pypi.org` is unavailable in my country if that's the reason of the problem.

Comment: What is `cp720`? Is it the encoding of your console?

Comment: @phd I really don't know, how to find out what `cp720` is?is there any way to fix this problem?i really need to use pip because i have to install `ordereddict` on my python library

Comment: [Code page 720](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_720) is Arabic encoding. It seems your computer is configured for it but Python 2.6 is too old and doesn't know the encoding. Change your console encoding with `chcp` or upgrade Python.

Comment: @php thank you for your attention, that worked for me but when i tried to install ordereddict it said this version no longer support by python team.so now i'm going to uninstall python, setuptools and pip and install a new version again. What version of python should i install?? I only worked with 2.6 version.

Comment: In Python 2 line — at least 2.7.15. In Python 3 ­— Python 3.6; I consider 3.7 too young, not all libraries updated yet. `collections.OrderedDict` is a part of Python library since [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).